# Google-cloud-sdk install issue WSL2

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu-18.04, python-3.8, wsl-2, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to contribute to an open source project called [oppia](https://github.com/oppia) and this is my first time interacting with google cloud.

Any insights into this?

When I [follow their instruction for WSL2 on Windows](https://github.com/oppia/oppia/wiki/Installing-Oppia-%28Windows%3B-Python-3%29), everything runs smoothly until I get to the portion where google-cloud-sdk and it's sub components are installed, It hangs (for hours) on 'Create update staging area.'

Any obvious issues for this error? I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10 with Python 3.8.15 (all recently installed/updated) all per the Oppia instructions. I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere online. Steps I've taken so far:

Updated firewall to allow incoming/outgoing traffic

Log errors via GCS_DEBUG_LOG

Updated $CLOUDSDK_PYTHON to path

Delete/reinstall g cloud

Manual install GCloud (seems to mess with Oppia configs)